# Something unexpected happened

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to play with handling unexpected exceptions, but cannot make it to work. This is example from: [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_unexpected/)

```
// set_unexpected example
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

void myunexpected () {
  cerr << "unexpected called\n";
  throw 0;     // throws int (in exception-specification)
}

void myfunction () throw (int) {
  throw 'x';   // throws char (not in exception-specification)
}

int main (void) {
  set_unexpected (myunexpected);
  try {
    myfunction();
  }
  catch (int) { cerr << "caught int\n"; }
  catch (...) { cerr << "caught other exception (non-compliant compiler?)\n"; }
  return 0;
}
```

They say that output should be:
Output:

unexpected called

caught int

Which doesn't happen when I try it. My output is:
caught other exception (non-compliant compiler?)
I'm using VS2010 sp1

Comment: "Something unexpected happened."  Yeah, exceptions are like that.

Comment: In `g++` this behaves correctly; perhaps it's a quirk in VS2010?

Comment: Bjarne himself has said exception specifications are broken... not much point trying to use them or expecting good compiler support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbt5tew.aspx) of `unexpected` says:
*The C++ Standard requires that unexpected is called when a function throws an exception that is not on its throw list. The current implementation does not support this.*
So the answer is that VC10 is a non-compliant compiler.

Comment: D'oh, out of votes for today.  Otherwise I'd +1 this... it's a great answer.

Comment: For once, this is a good thing. Exception specifications are fundamentally broken (see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm for some explanation).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not implement the standard correctly. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skce93f2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The `int` is parsed, but not used.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ always issues [Warning C4290](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa28fef8.aspx) when function has exception specifiers. From the same article in MSDN: *"A function is declared using exception specification, which Visual C++ accepts but does not implement."* So, this compiler does not comply with standard.